# when I try to texture paint onto my mesh, my texture shows up in a random place on the mesh

Tags: texture-painting

I'm modeling a cello right now, and I finished modeling, so I moved onto texturing.  I want to texture paint an image of a cello onto it, but whenever I try to paint onto my mesh, the paint does not show up in the desired place.  Instead, it shows up in random weird places (see image below)
[image]
I have already tried recalculating the normals and that changed nothing.  I suspect it has something to do with my UV's, but I don't know what to fix or where to start.  If anyone knows how to fix this, any help is appreciated! :)

(PS, I will give the link to my file below)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All normals are flipped. It's inside out. In Edit mode, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and "Flip" to fix it.

Comment: thanks!  That fixed it